# NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate and Alternating Table View Cells

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode

I have a `UITableView` that updates from a `NSFetchedResultsController`. The `UITableView` has alternating row colours for even and odd rows. I need to add support for the insertion and deletion of objects, so I implemented the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` to handle this. However, now my alternating colour scheme fils after inserting anywhere but at the end. Any ideas on how to solve this without reloading the table view (and not loose my animations)?

Here is my code thus far:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
  CustomTableViewCell *cell = ...;
  indexPath.row % 2 == 0 ? [cell odd] : [cell even];
  return cell;
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)object 
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)deleteIndexPath 
     forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)insertIndexPath 
{
  switch(type) 
  {   
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:

      [self.mainTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:insertIndexPath] 
                    withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
      break;
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
      [self.mainTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:deleteIndexPath] 
                    withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The followings are what I did for one of my projects:

```
- (void)reloadRowsFromIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSInteger i = index; i < [items count]; i++) {
        [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
    }
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [indexPaths release];
}
```

`reloadRowsFromIndex:` is called within `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:`, with the first index path being changed.

Comment: Is this reloading the entire table? I have a fetched results controller with a few thousand records and this seems like it might kill it...

Comment: Ended up solving this by using: `[self.mainTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:self.mainTableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows]`.